# Issue a response based on the nameserver value?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I [found a website (nameserver.io)](http://nameserver.io/) which basically does this:

a) You enter the URL you want to redirect to
b) It Base32-encodes that URL inside the name server itself

You just go and take that name, put it as your domain nameserver, and voila, you're done. That's it.

Now this is not really clear to me:

This particular site seems to be using Route 53 in the background. As far as I understand, Route 53 has "hosted zones" (domains), which you must add EXPLICITLY before being able to interact in any way with a new domain through them. Is this site using some sort of hack to bypass this...

Plus, it issues a response based on the nameserver value. As I know, nameservers are on the lower end than HTTP, so how is it that a script might be able to read the actual domain's namservers on an HTTP level?

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be doing some black magic, but not really.

Their servers are not resolving addresses based on the resolution path.  They can't be.

You can't programmatically discover the name servers or anything else in the resolution path, from either side.

Route 53 is only being used to *resolve* the IP address of the two custom nameservers they're giving you. It is not what's being used to resolve the queries that get sent to those name servers.  That would be fundamentally contrary to the design of Route 53.

The name servers they are assigning to you are actually running on EC2 instances that are crafting and returning the DNS responses.  Route 53 is only resolving the name server addresses.

The Route 53 part is almost certainly done with simple wildcards, so that `*.1.nameserver.io`, for any value of `*`, returns the same A-record -- their DNS server running in EC2.

But here's how it likely works, end to end.  I once wrote a similar setup using TXT records.

Query hits their DNS server on the IP address returned for your custom name server, by Route 53.

They return an answer that points to their web server. (This is a web site redirection service.)

Their web server receives a request for your domain (because it's pointing to their name servers, which gave out the IP address of their web server when asked about your domain).  Let's say `www.example.com`.  They do the equivalent of `dig example.com ns` to find the names of the name servers for the domain for which their site just received a request.  They get back the coded answer and voilá, their web server knows how to write and where to send the redirect.